# Create a Vector3 position by angle differences

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a *player position*, a pointer indicating the players *view direction*, a *distance* and a *horizontal* and *vertical angle*. I want to calculate a *target position*:

- that is *distance* away from the *players position*
- that, from the    players *view direction*, is *horizontal angle* to
  the right and    *vertical angle* up

It's about positioning a Hololens-Application UI in a sphere around the player. The UI should i.e. be 40 degrees to the leftand 20 degrees up from the players view direction.

**Edit**: Added image to clarify. Given is the Player Pos (pX|pY|pZ), the radius (= length of the black bold line) and both angles in degree.

I'm looking for how to calculate the UI Center position (x?|y?|z?).

[image]

Comment: the question is **why** you insist to calculate something by yourself what is already provided by the API. Seems like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357004) than .. StackOverflow is about coding problems. If instead you are more interested in the maths behind it you rather should have asked this on [Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com) and it would have nothing to do with Unity which you tagged here

Comment: `RotateAround()` only works if you have a game object with a transform component attached. It works within this use case, since I'm manipulating a gameObject.
But in another case, for example if you want to shoot a raycast in the calculated direction, instantiating a gameObject for the purpose of manipulating it's position to calculate the target direction is not the right way. So while I'm very happy with the answer provided by you and CaTs, I've wanted to add the math way for the sake of completeness. I agree, the posted solution is not Unity-specific. But I didn't know that before.

Comment: The solution posted by CaTs is exactly that! It calculates the target position. You don't need to aply the calculated position to a transform.. you can use it like you want. Btw every GameObject automatically has a transform component. Even the UI stuff since RectTransform inherits from Transform as well

Comment: You're completely right! I'm sorry - crunch time. Not much sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Quaternion.Euler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) to create a rotation based on angles in world space and then get the desired result by multiplying it with a known position.

So by using your example you could find the position like this:

```
float radius, x_rot, y_rot;
Vector3 forwardDirection, playerPos;

Vector3 forwardPosition = playerPos + (forwardDirection * radius);
Vector3 targetPosition = Quaternion.Euler(x_rot, y_rot, 0) * forwardPosition;
```

Try check out the docs on [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) and [Quaternion.AngleAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) for more handy rotation stuff.

Comment: Nice, I like your `Quaternion * Vector3` solution better than my answer! It's way more readable and ofcourse less lines of code. @JonasZimmer again you might want to take care of the UI's rotation after this. This time it keeps the current rotation and does only change the position. But I guess you can figure out that you could simply reuse the `Quaternion.Euler` for the rotation ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set UI in front of player with the same orientation as the player
ui.transform.position = player.transform.position + player.transform.forward * desiredDistance;
ui.transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation;

// turn it to the left on the players up vector around the the player
ui.transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, player.transform.up, -40);

// Turn it up on the UI's right vector around the player
ui.transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, ui.transform.right, 20);
```

assuming you also want the UI to face the player, otherwise you have to set another rotation after this.

No need to calculate it yourself, the Unity API already does it for you (
see [Rotate around](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html))

Answer (score 1):

Answer by a mathematician:

To calculate the spherical position with the given information (distance between objects, x angle, y angle) you use trigonometry:

```
float x = distance * Mathf.Cos(yAngle) * Mathf.Sin(xAngle);
float z = distance * Mathf.Cos(yAngle) * Mathf.Cos(xAngle);
float y = distance * Mathf.Sin(yAngle);

ui.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(x,y,z);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding you correctly you want to create a UI that hovers above a point. I recently did a similar thing in my game. and this is how i did it.

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // use the ray cast to get a vector3 of the location your ui      
                                 // you could also do this manualy of have the computer do it the main thing is to 
                                  // get the location in the world where you want your ui to be and the
                                 // WorldTOScreenPoint() will do the rest
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Vector3 pos;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                pos = hit.point;
                pos.y += yOffset; // use the offset if you want to have it hover above the point
                ui.transform.position = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(pos); // use your main cammera here              
                // then either make your ui vissible or instanciati it here and make sure if you instanciate it 
                // that you make it a child of your cnavas


            }
        }
```

I hope this solves you problem. If i am not understanding what you are trying to do let me know and i will try to help.

Note: if you want to make the ui look farther away when you move away from the point scale the ui down as you move farther away, and scale it up when you get closer.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's more complicated than that. Further investigating shows that I'm basically looking for Spherical coordinates. I want a position on a sphere based on degrees.

Comment: sorry i was not able to help you more

Comment: Note that scaling might be a "trick" on a 2D device for faking distance but it is not working on a 3D device like the HoloLens where you actually see the depth of objects ( at least up to 5 meters)

Answer (score 0):

The diagram in the question is somewhat confusing:

- The axes are in the orientation of a right-handed coordinate system, but Unity uses a left-handed coordinate system.
- In terms of Euler angles, the part of the image labeled "x Angle" is actually the Y angle (rotation around Y axis), and the part of the image labeled "y Angle" is actually the X angle (around X axis).
- The two angles listed use a different sign convention. The Y angle (labeled "x Angle") is following the right-hand rule, while the other angle is not.

Jonas Zimmer has a great answer that follows the conventions in the image, but I'll try to do something a bit less confusing and follows more standard math conventions.

Here is some code for Unity written in C#, in YX rotation order, treating zero angle as forward (+Z), and follows Unity's conventions of a left-handed, Y-is-up, Z-is-forward coordinate system. Increasing Y angle rotates to the right, and increasing X angle rotates down.

```cs
public static Vector3 Vector3FromAngleYX(float y, float x)
{
    float cosx = Mathf.Cos(x);
    return new Vector3(cosx * Mathf.Sin(y), -Mathf.Sin(x), cosx * Mathf.Cos(y));
}
```

Also, I found this question looking to implement a Godot version, so here is a version for Godot Engine written in GDScript, in YX rotation order, treating zero angle as forward (-Z), and follows Godot's conventions of a right-handed, Y-is-up, Z-is-back coordinate system. Increasing Y angle rotates to the left, and increasing X angle rotates up.

```
func vector3_from_angle_yx(y, x):
    var neg_cosx = -cos(x)
    return Vector3(neg_cosx * sin(y), sin(x), neg_cosx * cos(y))
```